# 'Length' Property Undefined while iterating Array

Tags: javascript

Iterating an array to find the longest string. Each time I've received the error `Cannot read property length of undefined`. `Console.log` tells me that the length of the array as well as the length of the string are being read and understood so I cannot understand where there is an undefined property. In fact, I've just about tripled the original length of the program trying to make sure every variable is defined but still no good. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longest = 0;
  var array = str.split(" ");
  var arrayL = array.length;
  for (i=0; i<=arrayL; i++) {
    var currentWord = array[i];
    var currentL = currentWord.length;
    if (currentL > longest) {
      currentL = longest;
    };
  };
  return longest;
};

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Edit: While the below answers did solve the issue, I also just wanted to mention for people that may later google this thread that I also had to swap my final `if statement` from `currentL = longest;` to `longest = currentL` since `longest` is what I was ultimately returning.

Comment: you read error wrong :-) not `length` is _undefined, but object where you try get this property - undefined

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed but the length isn't. In other words, `i<arrayL`

Comment: Also, are you looking to return the longest word, or the index of the longest word in the array you created? Oh and you don't need the semi-colons at the end of your `for`, `if`, and `function`.

Comment: @j08691 I was trying to return the length of the longest word. And thank you for the semi-colon help, I'm still very much a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the bounds of your iteration

```
for (i=0; i<=arrayL; i++) {
```

Note that you are going to be looking for array[array.length] doing this and that will always be undefined because the 10th item in an array of 10 items is [9], [10] is undefined.

Also, please use var here

```
for (var i=0; i < arrayL; i++) {
```

Comment: Gosh, I had thought that would be a quick comment and vote to close as typo.

Comment: @torazaburo - So, a meta discussion then? Amusing since you don't really participate there but okay. Let's get into your misunderstanding so that you don't actively drive users away from the site.  *"One thing I can tell you is that if you start targeting downvotes at experts who are just trying to help, you will start to drive those people away. I've already seen this in a few cases."* -Brad Larson♦ (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/1026459) . Tactical downvoting is not encouraged, and it is called out for abuse. You should re-evaluate the way you use the site.

Comment: I defer to your meta expertise. In case you didn't already see it here's something possibly relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions. As you will see, opinions differ.

Comment: @torazaburo - Not really. The sentiment there is also to vote on content and not use your votes punitively or tactically. In addition, the only caveat posted would be "vote how you want" which is true to an extent. So you *can* vote like this, but you are doing a disservice to the community by doing it. Thanks for actively making the effort to undermine everyone else.

Comment: A rather one-sided appraisal of the discussion on meta, if I may say so. Certainly it is not correct to reject the very idea that opinions differ. For instance, one answer to a different question, with more votes than than the accepted answer to the question I referenced above, says "The question quality will continue to decline as long as we continue to reward the bad questions with answers." See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow.

Comment: That would be one of the answers there with *some* support at the time. However, that topic has changed since then and that sentiment be well received on meta at the moment. You may ask that question again if you like to see how it goes. Note also that the person you quote does not have the overall knowledge and outlook as the moderators such as Brad Larsen and Shog9 who *repeatedly* advise against this behavior. I know you only want to help, but you are not helping anyone by discouraging answers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of error prone hand-written loops for iterating over an array, why not take advantage of the functions that JS provides you - in this case `Array.prototype.map`:

```
function findLongestWord(s) {
    return Math.max.apply(this, s.split(/\s+/).map(function(w) {
        return w.length;
    }));
}
```

The `Math.max.apply(this, some_array)` is the standard JS way of calling `Math.max(a, b, c, d, ...)` with the given array instead of passing a list of parameters of unknown length.

In ES2015 you could use the even shorter:

```
function findLongestWord(s) {
    return Math.max(...s.split(/\s+/).map((w) => w.length));
}
```

Comment: While this gives you the longest word it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Note that Array.prototype.map() may need to be polyfilled for older versions of IE.

Comment: @TrueWill it is *long* past the time when we should be warning of the need for polyfills for old browsers to get support for ES5.   I actually raised this on meta-SO about a year ago.

Comment: If you're going to ES2015, then wouldn't `Math.max(...[for (x of s.split(/\s+/)) x.length])` be a bit cleaner?

Comment: @torazaburo I thought that list comprehensions hadn't made it in this time?

Comment: @Jasen nevertheless, this sort of boundary condition error is exactly the sort of thing that `.map` etc can trivially solve

Answer (score 2):

You read error wrong :-) not length is *undefined*, but object where you try get this property - undefined.
So *currentWord* is *undefined*
because you have wrong loop condition: `i<=arrayL`,
when `i == arrayL` - `var currentWord = array[i]` is *undefined* and you get error.

Just fix it: `i < arrayL`

Comment: It was a tactical downvote to try to persuade you to stop answering questions like this by a misguided and naive user. Hopefully that explains the downvote. As for the overall behavior, well, that is something that as a community we still actively deal with both in outlook on meta and in places like this in the wild. These types of downvotes are considered an abuse of the system. Please don't let them dissuade you from answering.

Comment: @TravisJ, thanks for explaining :-) also i really not think that it was typo, as suggest torazaburo